# disable junit execution in surefire with testng provider

Tags: maven, testng, surefire

We have a mixed testng/junit (3 and 4) project and have configured maven to have two surefire executions; one for junit and one for testng.

I noticed that between surefire 2.15 and 2.16 (and 2.17), our testng provider started executing some of our junit tests as well. So, I've been banging my head against the wall trying to come up with a way to convince the testng runner to NOT run junit tests at all (since it obviously has issues doing it properly). According to the testng documentation, it should respect the junit=false configuration or corresponding testng.junit system property. So I've been trying to convince surefire to pass that configuration, with no luck.

Below is my surefire configuration with three different attempts to pass this property in. The first execution executes just junit (548 tests). The second execution executes 15 testng tests (great!) and then another 240 of the junit tests (not all of them).

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    <include>**/*Test.groovy</include>
                    <include>**/*TestSuite.java</include>
                    <include>**/*TestSuite.groovy</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <testNGArtifactName>none:none</testNGArtifactName>
                        <junitArtifactName>junit:junit</junitArtifactName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>testngonly</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>-Dtestng.junit=false</argLine>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                          <testng.junit>false</testng.junit>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                        <configuration>
                          <properties>
                            <property>
                              <name>junit</name>
                              <value>false</value>
                            </property>
                            <property>
                              <name>verbose</name>
                              <value>true</value>
                            </property>
                          </properties>
                        </configuration>
                        <junitArtifactName>none:none</junitArtifactName>
                        <testNGArtifactName>org.testng:testng</testNGArtifactName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I suspect the reason is the fix for SUREFIRE-1019 (https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-1019) TestNG provider fails to execute JUnit4 tests, which intends to sort of make it run junit, except they seem to have forgotten the option in to disable the behavior.

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: I think this doesn't have to do with `testng.junit`, but rather with TestNG's [mixed mode](http://testng.org/doc/migrating.html)

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a bug in the maven-surefire-plugin - it executed only TestNG tests when there are projects with both TestNG and JUnit tests. There is a comment in the bug saying you can skip either JUnit or TestNG test by using junitArtifactName or testNgArtifactName respectively.
    
        
            
                
                    org.apache.maven.plugins
                    maven-surefire-plugin
                    2.15
                    
                        
                            
                            test-testng
                            test
                            
                                test
                            
                            
                                none:none

For reference: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-377

Comment: Just add a little bit information why the OP should try this. How does your solution helps?

Comment: Well, this is my knowledge of know to define which tests(TestNG or JUnit) to be executed by the maven-surefire-plugin. I run successfully similar example where I need the plugin to execute both TestNG and JUnit and for this defined 2 executions - one for each.

Comment: Sure, my point is your post turned up in the Low Quality Queue due to the code to text ratio I guess and I try to educate you in posting answers that pass the quality filter and/or don't get flagged.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't know about that. I will post more text in the future.

Comment: You know your post has an [edit] link so you can add some text explaining how the phase in maven can be skipped by using a specifc configuration called none:none? (I'm not a maven user so I've no clue what I'm talking about)

Comment: the jira link is broken